# SQL Server to combine multi rows into single row where col0=col1

Tags: sql-server

my table :

```
 previousid|CurrentID|Data
 | 1       | 2       | Data 1
 | 2       | 3       | Data 2
 | 3       | 4       | Data 3
 | 4       | 5       | Data 4
```

Result i look for :

```
Select .... where PreviousID=1 :

    |Col0|Col1|Col2  |Col3|Col  4|Col5| Col6  | Col7 | Col8
    |1   |2   |Data 1|3   |Data 2| 4  | data 3| 5    | data 4

Select .....where PreviousID=2

    |Col0|Col1|Col2  |Col3|Col  4|Col5| Col6  |
    |2   |3   |Data 2|4   |Data 3| 5  | data 4|
```

i tried to create some SQL server query to get result with no luck, please help me guys

Comment: That would result in an undeterminate number of columns, and you shouldn't aim for that.

However, you should take a look at recursive queries: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: And what if do you have 1000 rows? Then do you expect 1000 columns ?

Comment: is there any possible way to achieve this ?, i plan to limit connection between Previousid and cuurentid to 10, soo max column are 10 for 1 row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this in a few steps:

1. Declare and set a variable to use for our root node, and create a temporary table to store the results from our recusive query:
2. Insert the results from the recusive query into the temporary table
3. Generate and execute dynamic sql to `pivot()` the temporary table.
4. (alternate) Generate and execute dynamic sql to use conditional aggregation instead of `pivot()`:

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/MRFZC75180

---

test setup:

```
create table t (PreviousID int, CurrentID int, Data varchar(32));
insert into t values
  (1,2,'Data 1'),(2,3,'Data 2'),(3,4,'Data 3'),(4,5,'Data 4');
```

> 1. Declare and set a variable to use for our root node, and create a temporary table to store the results from our recusive query:

```
declare @PreviousId int = 2; 

create table #temp (PreviousID int
  , Level int
  , Col varchar(32)
  , Value varchar(32)
  , rn int
);
```

> 2. Insert the results from the recusive query into the temporary table

```
;with cte as (
  select PreviousID, CurrentID, Data, level = 0
  from t
  where previousId = @PreviousId
  union all 
  select c.PreviousID, c.CurrentID, c.Data, level = p.level +1
  from t c
    inner join cte as p 
      on c.PreviousID = p.CurrentID
)
insert into #temp
select p.PreviousId, t.level, x.col, x.value
  , rn = row_number() over (order by t.level, x.col)
from cte t
  cross apply (
    select top 1 
        PreviousId 
        from cte i 
        order by level
    ) as p (PreviousId)
  cross apply (
    values ('CurrentId',convert(varchar(32),CurrentId)),('Data',Data)
    ) as x (col,value);
```

results so far:

```
+------------+-------+-----------+--------+----+
| PreviousID | Level |    Col    | Value  | rn |
+------------+-------+-----------+--------+----+
|          2 |     0 | CurrentId | 3      |  1 |
|          2 |     0 | Data      | Data 2 |  2 |
|          2 |     1 | CurrentId | 4      |  3 |
|          2 |     1 | Data      | Data 3 |  4 |
|          2 |     2 | CurrentId | 5      |  5 |
|          2 |     2 | Data      | Data 4 |  6 |
+------------+-------+-----------+--------+----+
```

---

> 3. Generate and execute dynamic sql to `pivot()` the temporary table.

```
/* pivot */
declare @cols nvarchar(max);
declare @sql  nvarchar(max);
select @cols = stuff((
    select 
      ', Col'+convert(nvarchar(10),rn)
      from #temp  
      order by 1
      for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
    ,1,1,'')
select  @sql ='
 select Col0=PreviousID, ' + @cols +'
  from  (
    select PreviousID, Value, rn= ''Col''+convert(nvarchar(10),rn)
      from #temp 
    ) as t
 pivot (max([Value]) for [rn] in (' + @cols +')) p'
select @sql as CodeGenerated;
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

code generated:

```
select Col0=PreviousID,  Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6
  from  (
    select PreviousID, Value, rn= 'Col'+convert(nvarchar(10),rn)
      from #temp 
    ) as t
 pivot (max([Value]) for [rn] in ( Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6)) p
```

returns:

```
+------+------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+
| Col0 | Col1 |  Col2  | Col3 |  Col4  | Col5 |  Col6  |
+------+------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+
|    2 |    3 | Data 2 |    4 | Data 3 |    5 | Data 4 |
+------+------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+
```

---

> 3. (alternate) Generate and execute dynamic sql to use conditional aggregation instead of `pivot()`:

```
/* conditional aggregation */
--declare @cols nvarchar(max);
--declare @sql  nvarchar(max);
select @cols = stuff((
    select  
      char(10)+'      , ' 
      + 'Col'+convert(nvarchar(10),rn)
      +' = max(case when rn = '+convert(nvarchar(10),rn)+' then Value end)'
    from #temp 
    order by 1
    for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
  ,1,0,'')
select  @sql ='
select Col0 = PreviousID'+@cols+'
from #temp
group by PreviousID'
select @sql as CodeGenerated;
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

code generated:

```
select Col0 = PreviousID
  , Col1 = max(case when rn = 1 then Value end)
  , Col2 = max(case when rn = 2 then Value end)
  , Col3 = max(case when rn = 3 then Value end)
  , Col4 = max(case when rn = 4 then Value end)
  , Col5 = max(case when rn = 5 then Value end)
  , Col6 = max(case when rn = 6 then Value end)
from #temp
group by PreviousID
```

returns:

```
+------+------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+
| Col0 | Col1 |  Col2  | Col3 |  Col4  | Col5 |  Col6  |
+------+------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+
|    2 |    3 | Data 2 |    4 | Data 3 |    5 | Data 4 |
+------+------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think try with concatenating column and give them alias.
For better understanding go through this link **https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2985/concatenate-sql-server-columns-into-a-string-with-concat/**